# Link error LNK2019 when updating plugin to work with Max 2013

Tags: 3dsmax

This is a question related to the plugin update to work with 3ds Max 2013. Needless to say, this plugin works with all previous versions of 3ds Max.

I am getting link error LNK2019 on `BMMSplitFilename()` function. I am suspecting unicode issue being behind it.

Here is the full definition of BMMSplitFilename() as defined in bitmap.h of 3ds Max 2013 SDK:

```
BMMExport void BMMSplitFilename(const MCHAR *name, MCHAR *directory, MCHAR *filename, MCHAR *extenstion)
```

Can anybody tell me why am I getting LNK2019? And, what to do to resolve this error?

Comment: Are you compiling it with unicode character set, and have you added bmm.lib to the additional linker dependencies?

Comment: Thank you Rotem. We are compiling with unicode character set, and have bmm.lib in Additional Linker Dependencies. We have discovered however that we had to specify unicode on two locations:

Comment: Thank you Rotem. We are compiling with unicode character set, and have bmm.lib in Additional Linker Dependencies. We have discovered, however, that we had to specify unicode on two locations: (1) Configuration Properties > General > Character Set has to be set to 'Use Unicode Character Set'; and (2) Configuration Properties > Resources > General > Preprocessor Definitions has to be set to '_UNICODE;UNICODE;%(Preprocessor Definitions)'.   Thanks again.

Comment: That's strange - setting the first usually automatically sets the second. Perhaps someone deleted it manually by mistake. You should post your solution as an answer, perhaps it will be useful to others.

Comment: Hi Rotem. No other person had access to the Properties. It is bug, perhaps. I thought that 'Add Comment' is visible to all. How do I post the above as an 'Answer'?  Thanks.

Comment: 'Add Comment' is in fact visible to everyone. Regardless, you should have a link right below this comment to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

We are compiling with unicode character set, and have bmm.lib in Additional Linker Dependencies. We have discovered, however, that we had to specify unicode on two locations:

1. Configuration Properties > General > Character Set has to be set to 'Use Unicode Character Set'; and
2. Configuration Properties > Resources > General > Preprocessor Definitions has to be set to `_UNICODE;UNICODE;%(Preprocessor Definitions)`.

Comment: Yep, that sounds correct. 3dsmax 2013 is compiled with Unicode.